# Entity Framework: how to map multiple tables with different keys to one entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have a DB structure like this:

```
create table Person (
  ID bigint identity not null,
  FirstName varchar(100),
  LastName varchar(100),
  -- etc... lot's of generic fields that apply to a person, e.g. phone, address
)

create table Teacher (
  ID bigint identity not null,
  PersonID bigint not null,
  EmploymentDate date,
  -- plus a bunch of other teacher-specific fields
)

create table Student (
  ID bigint identity not null,
  PersonID bigint not null,
  EnrollmentDate date,
  -- plus a bunch of student-specific fields
)

create table SystemUser (
  ID bigint identity not null,
  PersonID bigint not null,
  UserName varchar(50) not null,
  -- plus any user specific fields
)
```

The relationship between `Person` and all the other fields is 1 -> 0:1, and each of the "subclasses" of `Person` has a unique key on `PersonID`.  A `SystemUser` may be the same person as a `Teacher` or a `Student`; in fact you could conceivably have a person who is all three.

Now, I want to make EF entities to represent `Teacher`, `Student` and `SystemUser`, each of which either actually inherits from `Person` (1st prize), or at least incorporates the `Person` fields in the class, implicitly mapping to both underlying tables.

I've found plenty of examples online where they share the same primary key, but none where they do not share the same primary key, i.e. `PersonID` on the derived tables maps to `ID` on the `Person` table.

How do you you do it?

Comment: I believe you're looking for [Table per Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx) inheritance? However it's odd that you "duplicate" the PK since `Person` itself should be unique with `Teacher`/`Student` just providing additional details.

Comment: @BradChristie - "The two rows are linked together by their shared primary key value".  I found lots of examples of this.  What I need is an example where they are *not* linked by their primary key, but rather by a FK on a unique key.  I could change the schema so that the derived tables do use PersonID as their PK, but I want to know if it's possible not to do it that way.

Comment: This kind of join usually involves a third linking table. i.e. `PersonTeacher ( PersonID, TeacherID )` (or the like). So the structure you have is a hybrid form of some other structural type (basically not "typical")

Comment: @BradChristie - that intersection table would be right for a many to many relationship.  I have a one to zero-or-one relationship...?

Comment: may be this will help you to get started http://www.techiesweb.net/entity-framework-code-first-inheritance-table-per-hierarchy-and-table-per-type/

Comment: @shaul: Correct. i guess my question is this: If you can't have a `Teacher`/`Student`/`SystemUser` without having first a `Person` why does each of those inherited types require their own ID?

Comment: @BradChristie - fair point.  I just kinda got into the swing of giving every table its own autonumbered identity column.  But there's no real reason to do that, I guess.

Comment: @BradChristie - I changed my model to the more conventional structure.  Please go ahead and post your comments as an answer so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in fact you could conceivably have a person who is all three.

If this is your requirement you must not map person together with other classes. You must still have separate `Person` class and separate `PersonDetail` class where `PersonDetail` can have derived `Student`, `Teacher` and `SystemUser` classes mapped with TPT inheritance. You must map the relationship between `Person` and `PersonDetail` as one-to-many to support that requirement.

One you map person with inheritance your model will have this properties

- One `Person` will be `Student`, `Teacher` or `SystemUser`
- If you will indeed have a real person who acts as more than one role, you will need multiple Person records in your database for every role - each with its unique primary key
- The role of existing `Person` record could not change - that means `Student` will always be `Student` and it could not be changed for example to `Teacher` without first deleting the `Person/Student` and creating new `Person/Teacher`.

Comment: +1 for noting that you can't have overlaps between different subclasses of Person - thanks!